# center image in simple jquery zoom plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to write a very very simple zoom plugin that should have just a button to zoom in, zoom out, and the pan function to move the image around.

For now I've writte the part to zoom in and zoom out.

My problem is that I can't find a way to center the image inside the "zoombox".

This is my code so far:

```
$.fn.zoom = function() {

    var img = this;

    img.attr("style", "-ms-transform: scale(1); -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%; -webkit-transform: scale(1); -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%").wrap('<div style="width: 400px; height: 400px; overflow: hidden;" class="zoombox" data-scale="1"></div>');


    $("body").on("click.zoom", ".zoomin, .zoomout", function() {

        if( $(this).hasClass("zoomin") ) {
            var zoomFactor = (Number(img.parent().attr("data-scale")) + 0.1).toFixed(1);
        } else {
            var zoomFactor = (Number(img.parent().attr("data-scale")) - 0.1).toFixed(1);
        }


        img.parent().attr("data-scale", zoomFactor);
        console.log(zoomFactor);

        img.css({"-webkit-transform": "scale(" + zoomFactor + ")", "-ms-transform":"scale(" + zoomFactor + ")"});        
    });

  };
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xM7r4/1/

I know the style is not the best but I'm just trying to make it works without think about the style of the code.

How can I center the image inside the box, thinking that I will have to apply a pan effect later that will change the `transform-origin` values?

PS: I care about compatibility only on Chrome and IE9 for now.

Comment: Using transform-origin centers the image based on the scale, but you're also hiding parts of the image with overflow hidden wich creates some new challenges, anyway -> http://jsfiddle.net/xM7r4/2/

Comment: Thanks but the behavior is not what I need, it should start centered and stay centered, and if I start on XY position the XY position should stay at the same coords

Comment: I just played around a little bit [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xM7r4/18/), it's not working but maybe it gives you a hint how to approach this. Unfortunately I don't have time to make it work for now.

Answer (score 0):

***edit for comment***

You are correct. Here I've updated to work with `transform-origin`. It takes the dimensions of the containing div and divides by two (to get the centerpoint of the containing div) and passes these into the image's css `transform-origin` property:

http://jsfiddle.net/xM7r4/23/

I've tested with different dimensioned images, and it works.

---

***original***

You'll need to move the image using `margin-left` and `margin-top` depending on if you are zooming in or out.

http://jsfiddle.net/xM7r4/21/

Since you are increasing your image by a scale of 1%, you need to move the margins accordingly, negative for zoom-in, position for zoom-out.

```
$("body").on("click.zoom", ".zoomin, .zoomout", function() {
    var imgWidth = $(img).width();
    var imgHeight = $(img).height();
    var scaleWidth = Math.floor(imgWidth * 0.01);
    var scaleHeight = Math.floor(imgHeight * 0.01);       

    if( $(this).hasClass("zoomin") ) {
        var zoomFactor = (Number(img.parent().attr("data-scale")) + 0.1).toFixed(1);
        moveLeft -= scaleWidth;
        moveTop -= scaleHeight;


    } else {
        var zoomFactor = (Number(img.parent().attr("data-scale")) - 0.1).toFixed(1);
        moveLeft += scaleWidth;
        moveTop += scaleHeight;
    }
    console.log(moveTop);
        console.log(moveLeft);

    img.parent().attr("data-scale", zoomFactor);
    console.log(zoomFactor);
        img.css({"-webkit-transform": "scale(" + zoomFactor + ")", "-ms-transform":"scale(" + zoomFactor + ")", "marginLeft": moveLeft, "marginTop": moveTop});        
});
```

Comment: Thank you, the example works but if I use an image with a different resolution it doesn't. Maybe I have to set the starting margins according to the size of the image?